# Keeping width of two tables same

Tags: html, css, html-table

Here I have 2 tables, I want these 2 tables' width to be same, when the Confirmer name is long the second table expands but the first one remains same, I want both of them to be of same width in any situation, how can that be done? Check this [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/iduciw/23/edit) example.

HTML:

```
<table>
<tbody><thead><tr><th>1.5 - STATE</th>
  </tr></thead><tr>
<td>
<b>Issued by </b>User Administrator <b>on</b><font face="verdana" size="1" color="red">           24/05/2013 06:43  
</font></td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>

<table>
<tbody><tr>
<th>
Confirmer
</th>
<th>Status</th>
<th>Date</th>
<th>Comment</th>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Pathak Chankey</td>
<td>
<img src="xyz.png">
</td>
<td>           24/05/2013 06:43  </td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Lastname Firstname</td>
<td>
<img src="xyz.png">
</td>
<td>           24/05/2013 06:43  </td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>User Administrator</td>
<td>
<img src="xyz.png">
</td>
<td>         24/05/2013 06:43  </td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
</tr>
</tbody></table>
```

CSS:

```
thead{
  background-color: grey;
}


table, td
{
  background:#fffAF0;
border: 1px solid black;
border-collapse:collapse;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add a container and set a width in your container then apply the 100% width to your tables like this

```
div{

  width:400px;
}

table {

  width:100%;
}

<div>
 <table></table>
 <table></table>
</div>
```

http://jsbin.com/iduciw/32/edit

Answer (score 1):

Why do not you use a single table?

```
<table>
        <tr>
            <th colspan="4">1.5 - STATE</th>
        </tr>       
    <tr>
        <td colspan="4"><b>Issued by </b>User Administrator <b>on</b><font face="verdana" size="1" color="red"> 24/05/2013 06:43 </font></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th> Confirmer </th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>Date</th>
        <th>Comment</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Pathak Chankey</td>
        <td><img src="xyz.png"></td>
        <td> 24/05/2013 06:43 </td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Lastname Firstname</td>
        <td><img src="xyz.png"></td>
        <td> 24/05/2013 06:43 </td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>User Administrator</td>
        <td><img src="xyz.png"></td>
        <td> 24/05/2013 06:43 </td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```